# Is there a strdup equivalent in icu unicode?

Tags: c, unicode, icu, strdup

The question is self-explanatory. I'm using the C API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it's easy to implement. It's just:

```
UChar *u_strdup(UChar *in) {
    uint32_t len = u_strlen(in) + 1;
    UChar *result = malloc(sizeof(UChar) * len);
    u_memcpy(result, in, len);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Steve-o: `memdup` is not a standard function that I've ever heard of.

Comment: Oops, ok looks like I was confusing with [`g_memdup`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-memdup) in glib.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but you could request one and file a bug.

However, ICU typically doesn't return memory the caller owns- it uses its own wrapped malloc/free functions and defines a custom deleter on objects. So, this would be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`_strdup, _wcsdup, _mbsdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). _wcsdup and _mbsdup are wide and multi byte versions of strdup.